# shotwell, export files locally

Tags: ubuntu, debian, photos, pictures

I can only publish my files from shotwell in facebook or flickr and other on-line services.

All I want to do is copy smaller resolution versions of my huge files in a pen drive for a friend.

Is there any plugin available to do that? simply 'publish' a collection in a local filesystem directory with an optional size reduction?

i tried to look on writing my own (was planning on getting the flickr plug-in and just removing all the complex upload code and replace to a simple local file io) but their plug-ins are written in something called vala which i never heard before and will undoubtedly make my few hours plan became a few days endeavor :(

PS: adding ubuntu and debian tags as it is the default installed photo manager on those distros, and there is no shotwell tag yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the `Export...` option under the `File` menu. The dialogue allows you to resize the selected images and alter the file format/type to use. Once you click OK, you will be prompted for a location to save the images, which could be your pen drive.

Comment: have no idea how i missed that?! i think i was focusing too much that it would be a "local filesystem" plugin for export that i completely missed it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is also possible to drag'n drop them out of the shotwell collection into an Filemanager Window.